# TypeError: Cannot read property 'facts' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a word randomizer, and it gives me this error:

```
            message.channel.send(item.facts);
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'facts' of undefined
```

and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'game',
    execute(message, args) {
        const gameChanger = require('../text.txt')
        const item = gameChanger[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChanger.length)];
        setInterval(() => {
            const item = gameChanger[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChanger.length)];
            message.channel.send(item.facts);
        }, 5 * 1000);

    }
}
```

Someone please help me

Comment: do `console.log(gameChanger)` after `const gameChanger = ...` to see what it is, if it's an empty array, change it (add facts) since it will cause you problems if the array is empty

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the variable `item` is undefined. This is probably because you are going out of bounds of the `gameChanger` array, which is causing `undefined` to be assigned to `item`.

Comment: could you tell me how to fix it? I am new to discord.js so I don't completely understand.

Comment: `gameChanger[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChanger.length)]` can go out of bounds. If the length is 0, then it would evaluate to gameChanger[0] which will return undefined. I suggest investigating why gameChanger is an empty array, or maybe you want to break out of the `execute` block if it is empty.